# How to set the timezone different from the client-side in Apache IoTDB?

Tags: time-series, timezone, apache-iotdb, iotdb

Since Apache IoTDB is a time series database, I want to know if IoTDB can set the timezone of data storage other than the timezone of client-side. How to configure time zone in interface of IoTDB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache IoTDB can change the time zone in both JDBC and session native interface connections. You can use `(IoTDBConnection) connection.setTimeZone("+08:00")` for JDBC interface or `session.setTimeZone("+08:00")` for session interface to set the time zone you want. In the CLI command line tool of IoTDB, the way to manually set the time zone through command is `SET time_zone=+08:00`.

Answer (score 0):

A time-series database is simply one that is optimized for storing time-series data.  The only requirement for time series data is that there is a timestamp associated with each record.  For example:

| timestamp | value |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 100 |
| 1 | 50 |
| 2 | 380 |
| 3 | -5000 |

That is time-series data.  Importantly, note that `timestamp`, is on an arbitrary scale. There's nothing to indicate the timekeeping system being utilized.  In other words, `timestamp=0` does not have any relationship to a calendar, clock, or time zone.  There's not even any indication of how much real-world time is represented between `timestamp=0` and `timestamp=1`.

Now, *in practice*, we might store a more meaningful value that actually aligns to a timekeeping system.  For example, we could decide to store [Unix Timestamps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time):

| timestamp | value |
| --- | --- |
| 1672531200 | 100 |
| 1672617600 | 50 |
| 1672704000 | 380 |
| 1672790400 | -5000 |

And *then* we could decide to interpret them in a more meaningful way:

| timestamp | value |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-01-01T00:00:00Z | 100 |
| 2023-01-02T00:00:00Z | 50 |
| 2023-01-03T00:00:00Z | 380 |
| 2023-01-04T00:00:00Z | -5000 |

But there's nothing in the storage of the original numeric timestamp to indicate a time zone, and thus no time zone to change.

The only thing that implies a timekeeping system at all is from the definition of a Unix Timestamp, which is the timekeeping system that I arbitrarily decided to use in this example.  In particular, Unix Timestamps are [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) based, `timestamp=0` is precisely `1970-01-01T00:00:00Z`, and there is 1 second between `timestamp=0` and `timestamp=1`.

Now then, you asked about *time zones*.  In the real world, time zones are a logical mapping between UTC and the local time that is decided by the government or peoples within a specific area.  The rules for time zones are loosely aligned to longitudinal lines of the Earth, but are somewhat arbitrary in practice.  Time zones also have irregularities, such as shifts for daylight saving time transitions, or occasionally for government-made decisions to change the local standard time.  Thus, the local time represented by a time zone may have *discontinuities* in its relationship to UTC.  (See the charts in the [`DST` tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/dst/info) for visual examples.)

Time series data, [by definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_series), needs to be based on discrete-time.  That is, its timestamps come one after the next.  Thus, given its potentially irregular nature, *local time* is a poor choice for a timestamp in time series data.

As such, you will generally not find any mechanism for changing the time zone used for storage in a time series database.  Any time series database that converts real-world timestamps into a numeric value for storage will need to store those timestamps in terms of UTC.

### TL;DR

No.  There is no mechanism to change the time zone used to store timestamps in a time-series database like Apache IoTDB (and others), because any timestamp that is associated with a real-world date and time will need to be based on a continuous† time scale such as UTC, in order for time-series analysis to be practical.

Instead, you can translate from UTC to a local time zone as you read and write data, handling cases of invalid or ambiguous local time (that may arise from DST transitions, etc.), at the time of conversion.

*† Yes, I'm glossing over [leap seconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_second), because few actual scenarios require accounting for them. YMMV.*